# xhtml2pdf doesn't embed Helvetica

Tags: python, django, pdf, pisa, xhtml2pdf

I'm creating a PDF with xhtml2pdf using Django. I'm sending that PDF to print, but then they say that some Fonts are not embed. I have a Helvetica font, but I didn't use Helvetica in the PDFs.

Here you have a Screen Shot of the properties of the PDF

[image]

As you see, Guilles'ComicFont and TF2Secondary are correclty embbeded, but not with Helvetica.

Here you have my view that generates the PDF:

```
def generate_pdf(request, book, order):
    try:
        book = Book.objects.get(pk=int(book))
        order = Order.objects.get(identificador=order, cuento=book)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        raise Http404


    data = {}
    data = ast.literal_eval(order.datos_variables)

    data['order'] = order

    template = get_template(order.book.plantilla_html)
    html  = template.render(Context(data))

    url = '/Users/vergere/dev/media/pdfs/%s.pdf' % order.identificador

    fichero = open(url, "w+b")
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('utf-8'), dest=fichero, encoding='utf-8')

    fichero.seek(0)
    fichero.close()


    order.url_pdf = '%s.pdf' % order.identificador
    order.contador_libro = numero
    order.codigo_libro = country_code
    order.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('order_single', kwargs={'pedido': order.pk}))
```

And here my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Background</title>
        <style>
            @page {
                background-image: url("cuento1/img/portada.jpg");
                size: 213mm 216mm;
            }

            @font-face {
              font-family: Helvetica;
              src: url(pdf_generator/helvetica.ttf);
            }
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Gilles';
                src: url(pdf_generator/cuento1/gilles/gilles.ttf);
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
            }
            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Secondary';
                src: url(pdf_generator/cuento1/tf2_secondary/tf2_secondary.ttf);
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
            }
            * {
                box-shadow:none !important;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                text-shadow: none !important;
                font-family: 'Gilles';
            }
            body{
                font-family: 'Gilles';
            }
            p {
                color: #464439;
                display: block;
                font-weight: normal;
                position: absolute;
            }
            .page-1 p, .page-2 p{
                font-family: 'Secondary';
                font-size: 40px;
                line-height: 1.3em;
                position: absolute;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pdf:nextpage name="p1" />
        <pdf:nextpage name="p2" />
        <div class="page-6 page-dedicatoria">
            {{order.dedicatoria}} <br /> {{order.de}}
        </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Anyone knows why is using Helvetica? Or there is any way to embed Helvetica? I'm trying with "@font-face" but It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Helvetica is one of the standard fonts that every PDF renderer has to have available. Therefore it doesn't have to be embedded.

A possible solution would be to use another sans-serif font instead of Helvetica. On windows e.g. Arial. On OSX e.g. Helvetica Neue or Avenir. They look a lot like Helvetica, but are not standard PDF fonts.

In your stylesheet, specify  a new font for all elements;

```
* {
    font-family: Avenir;
}
```

Comment: The people in the printing company says that they can not print without all fonts.

Comment: Most PDF generators have an option to embed all fonts. Have a look at the `xhtml2pdf` documentation.

Comment: I did, the only way is using "@font-face" that works for all the Fonts except for Helvetica.

Comment: But the problem is that Helvetica is added automatically, I can't change Helvetica. (I'm not using Helvetica in my PDF)

Comment: Try setting a default font for all elements in your stylesheet.

Comment: I did, check the question on the part of HTML: * {
                box-shadow:none !important;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                text-shadow: none !important;
                font-family: 'Gilles';
            }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58965/discussion-between-marcos-aguayo-and-roland-smith).