# Remove font using iText

Tags: pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, itext

I have a problem with my PDFs. They have a default font, Helvetica. This font is unused, but I need to develop a script that automatically deletes this font.

After asking two questions:

[Unset PDF font with script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327398/unset-pdf-font-with-script)

[xhtml2pdf doesn't embed Helvetica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203219/xhtml2pdf-doesnt-embed-helvetica)

I finally discover iText. I've been trying to work with this library, and I made a few successful tests with Unembeding Fonts ([example](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/fonts/UnembedFont)). But I can't find anything about deleting a whole font from de PDF.

Thanks a lot

Comment: If the font is unused, then the `removeUnusedObjects()` will remove it. If the font isn't removed, then your allegation that it is unused is wrong. Show us the PDF and we'll tell you where it's used. Also: why bother removing Helvetica? The font probably isn't embedded anyway.

Comment: I've tried using removeUnusedObjects() and it's not working. maybe the Helvetica is used in a blank space or something. I have to remove because my printing company can't print the PDF without all the fonts. And this Helvetica font is not embedded.

Comment: If you remove Helvetica and Helvetica is used for a blank space or something, then your printing company will most certainly not be able to print the document because you'll make the document corrupt. Why didn't you create your documents as PDF/A documents?

Comment: I don't know, the company send us a document with the specifications and I think they need PDF-X. We use a software named xhtml2pdf. What we do now is I open every pdf with Adobe Acrobat Pro, and use the "Preprint" button and the adobe acrobat deletes me this font. I'm losing 5h a day doing this. And I want to use iText or any other software to create an script. Thanks for taking your time to answer me